# How to create a nested type using Reflection.Emit?

Tags: .net, reflection

I have a very complex need to create a class using Reflection Emit package. The class is a simple DTO and will be used with WCF to define services. Simple, really. However, I **must** use a nested type.

My current tests doesn't work. I can create the main type but I'm unable to create the nested type.

```
var serviceClassBuilder = _module.DefineType("something", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class);

// Create a nested class that will hold the input definition
var nested_type_builder = serviceClassBuilder.DefineNestedType(className,
    TypeAttributes.NestedPublic | TypeAttributes.Class |
    TypeAttributes.SequentialLayout);

serviceClassBuilder.CreateType(); // <-- NOT WHAT I EXPECTED!
```

There aren't any nested types in the class created. Is it possible? The classes are as simple as above. I've read above some limitations of the Emit package, but I'm not sure it applies to such a simple example as the one I used.

I even tried adding the line below before the create type:

```
nested_type_builder.CreateType();
```

Even though I think that the first builder should have done a cascade execution of CreateType, after all, I don't need to call anything to create methods, the assembly that hosts the type, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you have to call `nested_type_builder.CreateType()`, or you'll get an exception.

But if I did that, it behaved strangely. The `Type` returned from `serviceClassBuilder.CreateType()` doesn't seem to contain any nested types, at least if you look at them using `GetNestedTypes()`. *But* if you actually save the assembly to the disk and look at it, it contains the nested type exactly as it should.

So, if you only need to work with the generated assembly file, you should be fine. I think the behavior of `GetNestedTypes()` of the type returned by `TypeBuilder` is a bug.

Comment: I never occurred me to save it to disk. I'll try that. I need the types during execution, but so far I have no problem with saving and then loading the dll.

Comment: Ow, one other thing: not calling `nested_type_builder.CreateType()` prior to `serviceClassBuilder.CreateType()` **won't** raise an exception. My guess is it should.

Comment: Weird, it did raise an exception for me.